# how to add multiple css style to same view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Kendo mobile for my app,I have suitation that i need to add multiple class to my View ,when the **PostedImageUrl** is not null, i need add some class based on UI and when the **PostedImageUrl** is null i need to change UI, How i can achieve this kindly suggest.

```
  <div data-role=view>
  <ul class="oneClass"  data-role="listview" id="Feeds-listview" data -bind="foreach:data">
  <li style="background-color:#FFF;white-space:normal">
  <div style="width:100%">
  <label  class="profile-username front" data-bind="text:username"></label>
   <div style="float:left">
     <span data-bind="text:userId" style="display:none"></span>
   <div style="padding:0px!important">
    <img class="profileimage fimage" data-bind="attr: { src:ImageSrc }"  />
  </div>
   </div>
 <div style="float:left">
  <img class="emoji" data-bind="attr: { src: emoji }" />
  </div>
   <input type="checkbox" class="listcheckbox "/>
  <div data-bind="if:delete" class="delete">
   <a href="#" id="delete" data-bind="click:$root.Delete"><img 
   src="images/bin.png" style="width:24px;height:24px;float:right;margin-
   top:10px;" class="front" /></a> 
 </div>
 </div>
  <div >
    <span data-bind="text:PostedImageID"></span>
         <img style="height: 200px;width: 300px;margin-top: 10px;" data-
      bind="attr: { src:PostedImageUrl }" />
   </div>
           <div data-bind="click:$root.Like" class="Like" >
      </div>
          <a href="#" data-
      bind="click:$root.open"class="two"style="float:right;margin-top:47px">
     <span class="count" data-bind="text:TotalCount"></span>
                          top:-10px" />
  </span>
  </a>
  <span class="" data-bind="text:createdAt"></span>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <div>
```

Comment: use js, you can update any style you want

Comment: Thanks for your time,Is there any examples regarding changing css according to change in value

Comment: hi @kitty sarvaj, could you show me the HTML rendered by your code (the html have `PostedImageUrl`?) they are image URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe, use `$("img").on("load", function() { .. }`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img").on("load", function() {
    alert('SRC updated!: ' + $(this).attr("src"));
  });

});
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/b4ujn03w/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").on("load", function() {
    alert('SRC updated!: ' + $(this).attr("src"));
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("img").attr("src", "http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/5700000/Random-random-5719763-1280-800.jpg");
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("img").attr("src", "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff");
  }, 3000);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30800000/-Random-random-30843841-1920-1080.jpg' />
```